# bug in calculation hash-object , with content of '1' character?

Tags: bash, git, hash, git-bash

i have a git file (e.g file1.txt), and inside of it i have character 1.
`echo -e 1 | git hash-object --stdin  => d00491...39d4d`.
**but it's not ok with**
`echo -en 'blob 2\01\n' | shasum ==>a1ff5...f6df` because it not consider `1` as character and calcuate `\01` as seprate character.`=> blob 2`

i found that this type of convert not working with numeric content .

but starting with alphabet is fine !! such as .
`echo -e 'blob 2\0w' | shasum ==> e556b8...52ef`.
`echo w | git hash-object --stdin ==> e556b830c...052ef`.

any idea for calc hash-object ,starting with pure numeric content?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about. `echo -en 'blob 2\01\n'` outputs `b`, `l`, `o`, `b`, a space, the ASCII character SOH (`0x01`), and a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo -en 'blob 2\01\n' | cat -v
```

doesn't produce what you want, the result is `blob 2^A` instead of `blob 2^@1`.

What you want is

```
echo -en 'blob 2\00001\n' | cat -v
blob 2^@1
```

This is because `\0` starts a numeric sequence for `echo` and then `echo` expects up to 3 digits. That is `\01` for `echo` is 1 character with code 1; to produce `\0` + `1` you need to use `\0000` for character with code 0, then the next characters is 1.

```
echo -en 'blob 2\00001\n' | sha1sum 
d00491fd7e5bb6fa28c517a0bb32b8b506539d4d  -
```

Voila!

Comment: is there any way without padding ?want normal way for all type. also thanks for your answer @phd

Comment: For `\0` [`echo`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) expects up to 3 digits. If the next character is a digit you must use padding, no way around it. You can use `\x00` to shorter the padding using hex. You can use [`printf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) instead of `echo` passing `1` as parameter to format: `printf 'blob 2\0%s\n' 1`.

Comment: BTW, `{ echo -en 'blob 2\0'; echo -en '1\n'; } | sha1sum`.